# How to determine basis transformation for state vectors given a Hamiltonian written in two bases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, linear-algebra

A same system can be written in two basis:

$$\psi^\dagger H_1\psi=\begin{bmatrix}c_k^\dagger&c_{k+\pi}^\dagger \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}A&iB\\-iB&-A \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}c_k\\c_{k+\pi} \end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$\phi^\dagger H_2\phi=\begin{bmatrix}a_k^\dagger&b_{k}^\dagger \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0&A-iB\\A+iB&0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a_k\\b_{k} \end{bmatrix} \, .$$

I want to find the relation between the $\psi$ and $\phi$ bases.

One can see $H_2=U^\dagger H_1 U$ with
$$U=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1 \end{bmatrix}$$
I think $\phi=U\psi$. Am I right? $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not same, one can see from above equations.

Comment: Are $H_1$ and $H_2$ the same Hamiltonian written in two different bases?

Comment: Yes. Both are the same Hamiltonian with different basis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a $U$ such that $H_2 = U^\dagger H_1 U$.
Basis transformations should preserve the inner product, so given two representations of the state, $\psi$ and $\phi$, we must have

\begin{align}
\psi^\dagger H_1 \psi &= \phi^\dagger H_2 \phi \\
&= \phi^\dagger (U^\dagger H_1 U)\phi \\
&= (\phi^\dagger U^\dagger) H_1 (U \phi) \\
&= (U \phi)^\dagger H_1 (U \phi) \, .
\end{align}
Therefore, $\psi = U \phi$.

So you got it backwards :-)