# Basis transformation of eigenvectors of Hamiltonian written in different basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, lattice-model

There is a very famous topological model, Su-Schrieffer Heeger (SSH) model, according to which the hopping strength between even and odd sites is different. i.e.
[image]

Now, there are two ways one can write Hamiltonain for this system:

**First way:**

$c_n^\dagger$ are creating operator at site $n$. Hamiltonian ($\tilde{H_1}$) can be written as:
$$\tilde{H_1}=\sum_{n=1}^L[\frac{t+\delta t (-1)^n}{2}]c_n^\dagger c_{n+1}+H.C.$$

After converting this into k-space one can find following:

$$\psi^\dagger H_1\psi=\begin{bmatrix}c_k^\dagger&c_{k+\pi}^\dagger \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}A&iB\\-iB&-A \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}c_k\\c_{k+\pi} \end{bmatrix}$$
with $A=-t\cos(k)$ and $B=-\delta t \sin(k)$

**Second way:**

Second way to write Hamiltonian for the same system is to consider solid sites (in above picture) as $a_n^\dagger$ and open sites as $b_n^\dagger$. Now Hamiltonian ($\tilde{H_2}$) is:
$$\tilde{H_2} = \sum_{n=1}^L [(t+\delta t)a_n^\dagger b_n+(t-\delta t)b_n^\dagger a_{n+1}]+H.C.$$
in k-space it looks like following:
$$\phi^\dagger H_2\phi=\begin{bmatrix}a_k^\dagger&b_{k}^\dagger \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0&A-iB\\A+iB&0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a_k\\b_{k} \end{bmatrix} \, .$$
with $A=-t\cos(k)$ and $B=-\delta t \sin(k)$.

I have not written all the steps to convert Hamiltonian into k-space becuase it will be very messing to write all equations here but I am 100% sure that I have done everything correct till here.

**My main goal:**

My main goal is to first write wavefunction for this system in $\psi^\dagger=\begin{bmatrix}c_k^\dagger &c_{k+\pi}^\dagger \end{bmatrix}$ basis i.e. (One can find eigen-vector easily but let's say it looks like following:)
$$|WF_1\rangle = (X_1c_k^\dagger + X_2c_{k+\pi}^\dagger)|0\rangle$$

with $X_i$'s as some known terms. After that I want to convert this $WF_1$ into $\phi_k^\dagger=\begin{bmatrix}a_k^\dagger &b_{k}^\dagger \end{bmatrix}$ basis. i.e. I want to write it as:
$$|WF_2\rangle = (Y_1a_k^\dagger + Y_2b_{k}^\dagger)|0\rangle$$
What will be $Y_i$'s?

In [previous version](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/398221/how-to-determine-basis-transformation-for-state-vectors-given-a-hamiltonian-writ) of this question I didn't give this much details becuase I thought finding a unitary matrix to convert one basis into other is enough but after some kind comments I find that I needed to write all details.

I know I can find $WF_2$ directly from $H_2$ but for some reason I don't want to do that.

Sorry for confusing notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are asking is actually not quite related to the physical system (Hamiltonian). Instead, you are only asking how to change a state from basis $\{ c \}$ to $\{ a, b \}$.

First, the 1st way you wrote down is actually slightly different from the 2nd way: if you imagine you have L unit cells (2L sites), then your "$n$" in the first way should range from 1 to $2L$. Thus, the range of your "$k$" is also different from the k in the second way.

Thus, your true question is: "for $a_{n}=c_{2n-1}, b_{n}=c_{2n}$, how is the Fourier mode related to each others?"

I will just do one of them here,

\begin{align}
c_{\tilde{n}}:=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}\sum_{p=1}^{2L} c_{\frac{\pi}{L}p} e^{i(\frac{\pi}{L}p)\tilde{n}} \\
a_{n}:=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_{q=1}^{L} a_{\frac{2 \pi}{L}q} e^{i(\frac{2\pi}{L}q)n} \\
=&c_{2n-1}\\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}\sum_{p=1}^{2L} c_{\frac{\pi}{L}p} e^{i(\frac{\pi}{L}p)(2n-1)} \\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}\sum_{q=1}^{L} c_{\frac{\pi}{L}q} e^{i(\frac{\pi}{L}q)(2n-1)}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}\sum_{q=1}^{L} c_{\frac{\pi}{L}(q+L)} e^{i(\frac{\pi}{L}(q+L))(2n-1)} \\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}\sum_{q=1}^{L} \left[ c_{\frac{\pi}{L}q} e^{-i(\frac{\pi}{L}q)}- c_{\frac{\pi}{L}q + \pi} e^{-i(\frac{\pi}{L}q)} \right] e^{i(\frac{2\pi}{L}q)n} \\
\implies &  a_{\frac{2 \pi}{L}q} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ c_{\frac{\pi}{L}q} - c_{\frac{\pi}{L}q + \pi}  \right]e^{-i(\frac{\pi}{L}q)} \\
\text{or } & a_{2 \tilde{k}} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ c_{\tilde{k}} - c_{\tilde{k} + \pi}  \right]e^{-i \tilde{k}} 
\end{align}

This means $a_{2 \tilde{k}}$ is the superposition between the $\tilde{k}$ and $\tilde{k}+\pi$ in the original basis, with some phase shift. I believe you can figure the same relation for $b$, do the inverse, and plug it into your state to find the relation between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Please have a look if I am doing everything correctly:
$b_{n}=c_{2n} \implies b_{2\tilde{k}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ c_{\tilde{k}} + c_{\tilde{k} + \pi}  \right]$ which gives $c_{\tilde{k}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ a_{\tilde{2k}} e^{ik} + b_{\tilde{2k}}  \right]$ and 
$c_{\tilde{k}+\pi}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ -a_{\tilde{2k}} e^{ik} + b_{\tilde{2k}}  \right]$. So, $|WF_2\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ (X_1-X_2) e^{-ik}a_{\tilde{2k}}^\dagger +(X_1+X_2) b_{\tilde{2k}}^\dagger  \right]|0\rangle$

Is there anyway to get $a_{k}^\dagger(b_{k}^\dagger)$ instead of $2k$.

Comment: What if I take $H_1=\sum_{n=1}^L [(t+\delta t)c_{2n-1}^\dagger c_{2n}+(t-\delta t)c_{2n}^\dagger c_{2n+1}]+H.C.$

Comment: $\tilde{k}$ in $c_{\tilde{k}}$ is denser than k in $a_k$, so $a_{2\tilde{k}}$ include all the allowed k already.

Comment: For your more staggered Hamilonian, a unit cell will include more sites, let's call them $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$. It's easy to follow the same recipe, and each $a_i$ will be a linear superposition of $c(k),c(k+\pi/2),c(k+\pi), c(k+3\pi/2)$.